# How to migrate from AetherRepository to MavenBndRepository?

Tags: java, osgi, nexus, bndtools, obr

We have a Nexus Maven repository with the OBR plugin, that has been service our dependencies for our BndTools projects for years.

We configured the AetherRepository to refer to that obr.xml url (generated by Nexus), and that worked fine.

Now after upgrading BndTools to the latest version, the AetherRepository no longer works and should be replaced with the MavenBndRepository, but if I understand this right I need to supply an index file listing everything that's inside that repository.

Is there a way that I can generate this file somehow? We have a lot of stuff in that Maven repo...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an xml file containing the index of the repository (using the [OSGi repository schema](https://osgi.org/xmlns/repository/v1.0.0/repository.xsd)), the you can use the `aQute.bnd.repository.osgi.OSGiRepository` repository type to access the content.

Comment: Ok, looking into this, I'll try to get this to work. Is it correct that there is no mention at all from this plugin in the docs?https://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/610-plugin.html